# Rails select the object with the highest COUNT in a GROUP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The goal is to select the `Store` in which a `Coupon` is most used at.

Currently, I have this, and it works (broken down for explanation):

```
# coupon.rb
  has_many :redemptions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores

  def most_popular_store
    stores.find(        # Return a store object
      redemptions       # Start with all of the coupon's redemptions
      .group(:store_id) # Group them by the store_id
      .count            # Get a hash of { 'store_id' => 'count' } values
      .keys             # Create an array of keys
      .sort             # Sort the keys so highest is first
      .first            # Take the ID of the first key
    )
  end
###
```

And it's used like this:

```
describe 'most_popular_store' do
    it 'returns the most popular store' do
        # Create coupon
        coupon = FactoryGirl.create(:coupon)

        # Create two different stores
        most_popular_store = FactoryGirl.create(:store, coupons: [coupon])
        other_store        = FactoryGirl.create(:store, coupons: [coupon])

        # Add redemptions between those stores
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:redemption, 2, coupon: coupon, store: other_store)
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:redemption, 5, coupon: coupon, store: most_popular_store)

        # Verify
        expect(coupon.most_popular_store.title).to eq most_popular_store.title
    end
end
```

Like I said, the method works, but it looks monkeypatched. How can I refactor my `most_popular_store` method?

Comment: you could probably use counter_cache for the redemptions so you wouldn't even have to join.

Comment: What do you mean "it looks monkeypatched"? Are you looking for something that's a single query, or something that "looks nice"?

Comment: @eirikir I mean it seems like the sorting and ID selection could be handled in the query rather than after pulling the records down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your method actually doesn't work. `count` gives you a hash with keys as store_ids and values as counts, then you run `keys` on the hash, which gives you an array of store_ids. From then on, you have lost the counts, you are sorting by store_ids and grabbing the first one. The only reason your test passes is that you are creating the popular store before the other one, hence it gets a lower id (`sort` does the sort ascending by default). To get a correct result, make the following change:

```
redemptions       # Start with all of the coupon's redemptions
  .group(:store_id) # Group them by the store_id
  .count            # Get a hash of { 'store_id' => 'count' } values
  .max_by{|k,v| v}  # Get key, val pair with the highest value
                    # output => [key, value]
  .first            # Get the first item in array (the key)
```

Comment: Works great! Still seems a little long, but it does indeed work better than what I had! Thanks!

Comment: It can be handled by in a query.      
redemptions.group(:store_id).select("count(store_id) as cnt_store, store_id").order("cnt_store DESC").first.store_id

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this but making the computing on the SQL query? I dont want to load all the keys in memory and sort them just to return the first item