# Ruby on Rails - How to pick the least used enum value in a user table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my users table, every user will belong to a team.

For teams, I am using an enum on the model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
enum team:  [:team1, :team2, :team3, etc. ]
```

What I want to do is this:  when a new user is created, I want to basically count the number of users assigned to each team, and add the new user to the team with the least amount of people currently assigned to it.

I feel like I can *almost* get there with

```
User.group(:team).count
```

That gets me the counts for each team, but how do I select the one with the lowest count?

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks to this SO question:  [Rails select the object with the highest COUNT in a GROUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618823/rails-select-the-object-with-the-highest-count-in-a-group)

I just had to modify max_by to min_by and seems to be working just fine.

```
User.where(:team.nil?).group(:team).count.min_by{|k, v| v}.first
```